# Is there a way to yield variable from multi layer function or inner function?

Tags: javascript, python, generator

Like this code with ES6:

```
function* outer() {
    function* inner() {
        var a = 100
        yield a
    }

    var gen = inner()
    var result = gen.next()
    yield result.value
}

function caller() {
    var gen = outer()
    var result = gen.next()
}
caller()
```

Can I handle the inner`s generator result direct in caller without the bridge function of outer?
If no, is there a better design to resolve the generator auto-run and generator recursive?
Thanks

Another question? How about python?

```py
def outer():
    def inner():
        a = 100
        yield a

        b = 200
        yield b

    gen = inner()
    result = next(gen)
    yield result
    # it works not like js version
    # yield inner()


def caller():
    gen = outer()
    result = next(gen)
    print("caller result : ", result)
caller()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `yield*` inside a generator, you can yield all items from *another* generator:

```js
function* outer() {
    function* inner() {
        var a = 100
        yield a
    }
    yield* inner();
}

function caller() {
    var gen = outer()
    var result = gen.next()
    console.log(result);
}
caller()
```

Comment: Thanks. It`s what I want
And another question is if this code is python, is there a way like this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Python (well)

Comment: Python can use ‘yield from’， it likes ‘yield*’ in js